# How to adjust the height of each row of the dropdown list based on the content of the second column?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I created a dropdown list using the selectMenu jQuery widget and then created a dropdown component using it in the Angular so that I'm able to reuse the same component. Now, the problem which I am facing is that the dropdown list consists of 3 columns and the 2nd column contains the main content of each row. Now, whenever I am increasing the size (length) of the content to be put in the 2nd column, the heights of other two columns of each row are not adjusted dynamically. I'm confused on how to fix this issue? Given below is the image of the dropdown list, which I have created, with the unadjusted height of the row.

[image]

Here is the link to the codepen page with the example and the code which I have used: [Codepen Dropdown link](https://codepen.io/DG4/pen/RjzyJv). I tried fixing this issue by using `display:table-cell;` in CSS file but my effort went in vain. Please suggest how to fix this issue. Moreover. here is the output which I desire.
[image]

Given below is the code snippet.

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.mySelectMenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li, name, short, price;
        if (item.optgroup != currentCategory) {
          ul.append(
            "<li class='ui-selectmenu-category'>" +
            item.optgroup +
            "</li>"
          );
          currentCategory = item.optgroup;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        console.log(ul);
        name = li.text();
        short = item.element.data("short");
        price = item.element.data("price");
        console.log(li, short, price);
        li.prepend(
          $("<span>", {
            class: "short"
          }).html(short)
        );

        li.append(
          $("<span>", {
            class: "price"
          }).html(price)
        );
        if (item.optgroup) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.optgroup + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $("#options").mySelectMenu({
    width: 300
  });
  $("#options")
    .mySelectMenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("overflow");
});
```

```css
.ui-selectmenu-category {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  padding: 0.5em 0.25em;
  min-width: 290px;
}

.ui-selectmenu-category::after {
  content: "PRICE";
  float: right;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em 2px;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
  border-color: #cccccc;
  background-color: #e4ebf1;
  color: #000;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active.short {
  color: #2e6d99;
}

.ui-menu-item div.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  width: 290px;
}

.ui-menu-item .short {
  color: #2e6d99;
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 30px;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
}

.ui-menu-item .price {
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: -6px;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Custom Rendering</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="options">Select an Option:</label>
  <select id="options">
  <optgroup label="PREFERRED OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="L" data-price="$0.00">Standard Screw Adjustment dkjsahdksajd sdhsdl sdshad ;sldh sd;lsa d;lsajd</option>
    <option data-short="K" data-price="$0.00">Standard Screw Adjustment</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="STANDARD OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="C" data-price="$5.00" >Tamper Resistant - Factory Set</option>
    <option data-short="K" data-price="$6.00" >Handknob</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ADDITIONAL OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="F" data-price="$4.00">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
    <option data-short="G" data-price="$4.00">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
    <option data-short="H" data-price="$4.00" >Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use `Flex-box`.Add your code snippet.

Comment: @Meraj Khan, added it. Now, please tell me how to use flex-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using with `display:table` and `display:table-cell`

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.mySelectMenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
      var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
      $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var li, name, short, price;
        if (item.optgroup != currentCategory) {
          ul.append(
            "<li class='ui-selectmenu-category'>" +
              item.optgroup +
              "</li>"
          );
          currentCategory = item.optgroup;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
        console.log(ul);
        name = li.text();
        short = item.element.data("short");
        price = item.element.data("price");
        console.log(li, short, price);
        li.prepend(
          $("<span>", {
            class: "short"
          }).html(short)
        );

        li.append(
          $("<span>", {
            class: "price"
          }).html(price)
        );
        if (item.optgroup) {
          li.attr("aria-label", item.optgroup + " : " + item.label);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $("#options").mySelectMenu({
    width: 300
  });
  $("#options")
    .mySelectMenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("overflow");
});
```

```css
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item { 
  display:table; width:100%;
}
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px 1em 3px .4em;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
}
.ui-selectmenu-category {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  padding: 0.5em 0.25em;
  min-width: 290px;
}

.ui-selectmenu-category::after {
  content: "PRICE";
  float:right;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top
  padding: 1em 2px;
}


.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active {
  margin: 0;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    background-color: #e4ebf1;
    color: #000;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active.short {
  color: #2e6d99;
  
}

.ui-menu-item div.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  width: 290px;
  
}

.ui-menu-item .short {
  color: #2e6d99;
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 30px;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  position:absolute;

}

.ui-menu-item .price {
  font-weight: strong;
  width: 75px;
  margin-right: -6px;
 
}


.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Selectmenu - Custom Rendering</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="options">Select an Option:</label>
    <select id="options">
  <optgroup label="PREFERRED OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="L" data-price="$0.00">Standard Screw Adjustment dkjsahdksajd sdhsdl sdshad ;sldh sd;lsa d;lsajd</option>
    <option data-short="K" data-price="$0.00">Standard Screw Adjustment</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="STANDARD OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="C" data-price="$5.00" >Tamper Resistant - Factory Set</option>
    <option data-short="K" data-price="$6.00" >Handknob</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="ADDITIONAL OPTIONS">
    <option data-short="F" data-price="$4.00">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
    <option data-short="G" data-price="$4.00">Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
    <option data-short="H" data-price="$4.00" >Hex Head Screw with Locknut</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In `.ui-menu-item .short` class, after removing this statement, `position:absolute;` this code runs fine.

Comment: Actually, there is one more problem. When I hover the cursor on any row of this list, it seems to jump a little bit i.e it looks like that the hovered row is slightly shifted on top/bottom. But this behavior is not at all desired to me. Can you suggest something to fix it?

Comment: Because of you are adding a border at the time of hover on `.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-active` class

Comment: So, is there any way for fixing it when I require a border?

Comment: Yes you can add `.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper { border: solid 1px transparent; }`

Answer (score 0):

#### Very simple fix, add this:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item:not(.ui-selectmenu-category) {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: adding this makes the optgroup labels STANDARD OPTIONS and PRICE stick to each other and disrupts their alignment

Comment: @DG4 sorry I overlooked that, fixed my answer.

Comment: Doing this increases the opened dropdown menu width by way too much.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code add this `display: flex;`

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
display: flex;
height: auto;
flex-direction: row;
margin: 0;
cursor: pointer;
list-style-image: 
}
```

Comment: Doing this increases the opened dropdown menu width by way too much.

Comment: remove inline-stylesheet `width` you're apply to `ul` in html

Comment: Actually, there is one more problem. When I hover the cursor on any row of this list, it seems to jump a little bit i.e it looks like that the hovered row is slightly shifted on top/bottom. But this behavior is not at all desired to me. Can you suggest something to fix it?

Comment: because onhover to this class you give border.

Comment: I gave border to this because I needed the border. Isn't there any solution to this problem?

Comment: give border  rgba 1px transparent to same class before hover. then onhover you're not getting this issue